# java.io.IOException: Couldn't get lock for

Tags: java, filehandler

Get error as

"java.io.IOException: Couldn't get lock for ..\log\abc.log", 
not sure why this happen.

Can somebody help me out? Thank you

```
        logger = LogManager.getLogManager().getLogger(className);
        FileHandler logFile = new FileHandler(file);

        // create txt Formatter
        SimpleFormatter formatterTxt = new SimpleFormatter();
        logFile.setFormatter(formatterTxt);         
        logger.addHandler(logFile);
```

Comment: Could u post the logger property file?

Comment: Are you sure you can use ".." in the filename pattern?  I've never seen that done before.

Comment: I would assume that some other process already has the log file open...or you don't have permission to write to the location...

Comment: The message I'd clearly enough. What do you not understand?

Answer (score 6):

@Catheryan

I also had the same issue.
For me issue was:

```
private static final String FILE_PATH="/home/jeril/Logs.log";
handler = new FileHandler(FILE_PATH);
```

FILE_PATH was WRONG

Answer (score 3):

This issue is a long standing bug in `FileHandler` (reported way back in March 2005, in Java 4):

[JDK-6244047 : impossible to specify directories to logging FileHandler unless they exist](http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=6244047)

Quoting from the description of this bug:

> If you specify a patern to the FileHandler that contains directories
>   that don't currently exist then the FileHandler will fail to
>   initialise even if the directories can be created

Its mentioned that it has been fixed in Java 8. For versions earlier than 8, the workaround is to either not use any directory in the pattern used for a `FileHandler` or use a directory which actually exists on the disk.

Comment: Checking if the folder exists and if not, creating it before using the file handler solved the problem!

Answer (score 2):

I think this is due to  there being more than one instance of the logger that has it open or some other external application has it open with a read/write lock.